# Not able to remove check icon from input

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I have created a toggle selector and the behavior is correct now but I have a little UI issue and I can't figure out, what is it.

[image]

I have circled in red the issue I have, It's really minor but it's annoying. I do not want those `check` icons.

here is the code:

```
const Switch = 
            <form className="switch-field">
                <div className="switch-field-element">
                    <input
                        type="radio"
                        id="switch_left"
                        name="switchToggle"
                        value={TextContents.CreditsBundle}
                        onChange={this.toggleState}
                        checked={!this.state.toggle}
                    />
                    <label htmlFor="switch_left">{TextContents.CreditsBundle}</label>
                </div>
                
                <div className="switch-field-element">
                    <input
                        type="radio"
                        id="switch_right"
                        name="switchToggle"
                        value={TextContents.SubscriptionsBundle}
                        onChange={this.toggleState}
                        checked={this.state.toggle}
                    />
                    <label htmlFor="switch_right">{TextContents.SubscriptionsBundle}</label>
                </div>
            </form>
```

and the css associated

```
.switch-field {
  display: flex;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  }

.switch-field-element {
  position: relative;
  height: 80px;

}

.switch-field-element:not(:first-of-type) {
  margin-left: -60px;
}
  
  
  .switch-field input {
      position: absolute;
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
      opacity: 0;
  }
  
  .switch-field label {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    padding: 0px 80px;
    background-color:#f4f7f8;
    height: 50px;
    line-height: 50px;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: all .1s;
    color: #dfdfdf;
    user-select: none;
    border-radius: 40px;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: Source Sans Pro;
  }

  .switch-field label::after {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    width: 4px;
    height: 8px;
    border-bottom: 2px solid white;
    border-right: 2px solid white;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
  }
  
  .switch-field input:checked + label {
    background-color: var(--village-color-blue);
    border-color: var(--village-color-blue);
    color: white;
    z-index: 1;
    box-shadow: 0px 15px 20px -2px rgba(black, .1);
  }
  
  .switch-field label:first-of-type {
    padding-right: 80px;
  }

  .switch-field label:first-of-type::before {
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
  }

  .switch-field label:first-of-type::after {
    right: 12px;
    top: 9px;
  }
  
  .switch-field label:last-of-type {
    padding-left: 80px;
  }

  .switch-field label:last-of-type::before {
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
  }

  .switch-field label:last-of-type::after {
    left: 12px;
    top: 9px;
  }
```

Any idea how to remove these little checks ? thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can set visibility hidden to your radio buttons.

Try this:

```
input[type="radio"]:checked{
   visibility:hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change as per your requirement - [Live working demo](https://l1mt0.csb.app/)

```
 <form className="switch-field">
          <div className="switch-field-element">
            <input
              type="radio"
              id="switch_left"
              name="switchToggle"
              value={TextContents.CreditsBundle}
              onChange={this.toggleState}
              checked={!this.state.toggle}
            />
            <label
              className={toggle ? "lightgrey" : "blue selected"}
              htmlFor="switch_left"
            >
              {TextContents.CreditsBundle}
            </label>
          </div>

          <div className="switch-field-element">
            <input
              type="radio"
              id="switch_right"
              name="switchToggle"
              value={TextContents.SubscriptionsBundle}
              onChange={this.toggleState}
              checked={this.state.toggle}
            />
            <label
              className={!toggle ? "lightgrey" : "blue selected"}
              htmlFor="switch_right"
            >
              {TextContents.SubscriptionsBundle}
            </label>
          </div>
        </form>
```

css

```
.switch-field {
  display: flex;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.switch-field-element {
  position: relative;
  height: 80px;
}

.switch-field-element:not(:first-of-type) {
  margin-left: -60px;
}

.switch-field input {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
}

.switch-field label {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  padding: 0px 80px;
  background-color: #f4f7f8;
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 0.1s;
  color: #dfdfdf;
  user-select: none;
  border-radius: 40px;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: Source Sans Pro;
}

.selected::after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 9px;
  height: 17px;
  border-bottom: 2px solid white;
  border-right: 2px solid white;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  top: 10px;
  left: 20px;
}
.switch-field .uncheck label::after {
  left: 12px;
  top: 9px;
}
.switch-field input:checked + label {
  background-color: var(--village-color-blue);
  border-color: var(--village-color-blue);
  color: white;
  z-index: 1;
  box-shadow: 0px 15px 20px -2px rgba(black, 0.1);
}

.switch-field label:first-of-type {
  padding-right: 80px;
}

.switch-field label:last-of-type {
  padding-left: 80px;
}

.switch-field label:last-of-type::before {
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}

.lightgrey {
  background-color: #f4f7f8 !important;
}
.blue {
  background: #07b6d2c7 !important;
}
```

[working code](https://codesandbox.io/s/serene-snowflake-l1mt0?file=/src/styles.css:0-1472)

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Pwty.png)

[image]

Comment: Not sure to understand how it helps as my point was to remove the checks